# запустить python-скрипт через терминал, Java

Tags: java, python, macos, terminal

Не запускается *python*-скрипт, путь к файлу правильный. Та же самая команда запускается через терминал вручную.

```
String[] command = {"python3", "/Users/lounah/Documents/programming/PhotoMaker/createAccount.py",
        " " + name, " " + username + " " + email + " " + password};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process process = processBuilder.start();


StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("line: " + line);
    output.append(line);
}

process.waitFor();
```

> output = null

Comment: сделайте перед стартом `processBuilder.redirectErrorStream( true )`, может скрипт пишет какую-то ошибку.

Comment: откуда строка `output = null` берётся? Если вы попытаетесь `import sys; print(sys.argv)` скрипт выполнить, то что происходит?